# Getting 400 volley server error which is working from Rest client successfully

Tags: android, android-volley, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

Am getting 400 server error for volley get request for below url

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ('AEDALL')&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=
```

when i hit the same url from rest client its giving json response

Here is my code for volley request

```
private void convertCurrenctVolleyTask(String from, final String to, final String amount) {

    String url_yahoo = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ('"+from+to+"')&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=";

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CurrencyConverter.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.show();

    JsonObjectRequest GetCurrenciesjsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url_yahoo, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                    if (response != null) {
                            parseGetCurrencyResp(response,to,amount);

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(CurrencyConverter.this,
                            "Server error..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();

                }
            });

    ConfigVolley.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(GetCurrenciesjsObjRequest);

}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 8):

You will need to replace all occurences of a space(" ") with the %20 url_yahoo = url_yahoo.replace(" ", "%20");

Comment: your welcome, if you don't mind can you accept the answer since it worked.

Comment: I was getting a really weird error from my Phusion Passenger server. Just a "400" response with "invalid constant string", but only on Android < 23 and lower. Turns out I had a space in my URL. I guess Volley after that automatically fixes invalid encoding?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a properly formatted URL. You need to encode your URL parameters so that they do not contain invalid characters.

Try using [`URLEncoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) before using your `url_yahoo` like so:

```
String query = "select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ('"+from+to+"')";
query = URLEncoder.encode(query, "utf-8");

String env = "store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=";
env = URLEncoder.encode(query, "utf-8");

url_yahoo = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + query + "&format=json&env=" + env;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,am getting below formatted url with same 400

05-08 20:09:11.902: E/Volley(7509): [47873] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for       http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.xchange+where+pair+in+%28%27AEDAMD%27%29&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys%26callback%3D